# Azure Functions Application Insights Context

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

We've a bunch of azure functions log metrics against the execution context... you don't seem to be able to do this using the OOTB `TraceWriter`, or `ILogger` (at least in what i have seen) as there isn't an equivalent to what i assume would be named `log.LogEvent()`..

So.. this url (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#custom-telemetry-in-c-functions) shows a pattern for leveraging a `TelemetryClient()` inside of Azure Function to do the same, with examples for rolling your own for `EventTelemetry()` etc, however to ensure the correlation works you have to set the context for each thing you log:

```
var evt = new EventTelemetry("Function called");
evt.Context.Operation.Id = executionContext.InvocationId.ToString();
telemetryClient.TrackEvent(evt);
```

This all seems fairly logical, except i have a shared class (`TelemetryManager`) that helps creation of `TelemetryClient()` - so we don't have to repeat code in every, single, function that just news up a client with a series of additional settings.. this also implements a logging interface `ITelemetry` so that we have an interface later to unit test against, and lets you do.. (here using trace for simplicity):

```
static CustomTelemetryManager logger = new CustomTelemetryManager();
logger.Trace($"thing i want to trace: {x.value}");
```

`logger.Trace()` method simply does is call the `telemetryClient.TrackTrace()` method in the `CustomTelemetryManager()` class - some other methods are more complex.

Anyway, the interface is there so that when unit testing we can just do:

```
 // gets all the app insights key, and sets various other properties.        
static DebugLogger logger = new DebugLogger();
logger.Trace($"thing i want to trace: {x.value}");
```

and it will just `Debug.WriteLine()` instead of attempting to call out to AI

**Question 1**: Is there a "better" way to swap out Application Insights code for unit tests, as this is the only reason that we have this `ITelemetry` interface at all... to facilitate a dummy logger for unit tests.

Ultimately though, what i need to do, is give the `telemetryClient.TrackTrace()` the context of the invocation that is being executed, and the only way i have found to do that right now is, similar to the track event code above..

```
var trace = new TraceTelemetry($"i am a trace.");
trace.Context.Operation.Id = context.InvocationId.ToString();
logger.Trace(trace);
```

Because the `TelemetryClient` is shared over all functions, i need to apply the context to the metric directly before sending it to log..

**Question 2**: Is the only way i can do this.. something like:

```
public void TrackTrace(string msg, ExecutionContext ctx)
{
    var trace = new TraceTelemetry(msg);
    trace.Context.Operation.Id = ctx.InvocationId.ToString();
    client.TrackTrace(trace);
}
```

As this will mean modifying the interface, and then also mean for unit testing i shall also need to supply some sort of dummy context to the debug logger, which feels a bit clunky..

Somewhere in here, i think there is a simple tweak to simplify this needlessly confusing problem.. but i can't quite see the wood for the trees!

Comment: Your problem is not exactly clear to me. Maybe you could make your desired code more clear and highlight the exact issue? I don't see how setting the properties of `trace` prevents you from mocking `TelemetryClient`.

Comment: tbh @Mikhail i probably havn't explain it well, as i wrote that in a bit of a rush... i'll have another look - is there a way i should mock TelemetryClient ?

Comment: @m1nkeh did you ever find a good way to mock the TelemetryClient?

Comment: @AdamStapleton, i did not. It might be a lot easier now though.. i did this on Azure Functions v1.0 which didn't even support DI, and of course it's now on v3.0 which i *think* does??! I might take a look at this again, and update with a solution if i have time.

Comment: also @AdamStapleton i can't fully remember the actual gritty detail of this question... i didn't know much about Azure Functions when i wrote it, so it might be a really stupid question now! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the context in your `CustomTelemetryManager` constructor assuming you create a new `CustomTelemetryManager` object per invocation.

In the `CustomTelemetryManager` implementation you can always use the same static `TelemetryClient`, but since your `CustomTelemetryManager` has the context already, it just adds it to every call of `telemetryClient.TrackEvent()` call you make.

Comment: yep, of course i can... d'oh, see now why didn't i think of that.. wood for trees strikes again... same question as in the above comment though, is there a 'correct' way to mock (i'm not actually using a mocking framework atm) application insights that would let me lose the ITelemetry interface?